# Call a view within a view with different methods

Tags: django, redirect, view

I have two views, one to create an item and another to generate the global view of an instance of another object.In this view, I have a form and what I want is to redirect to the previous page after the processing of the view.

Basically :

```
def view1(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
         #heavy processing for the context
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))

def view2(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Simply add an element
    return view1(request)
```

Here's what I want to do. The thing is that, as you can see, the method is different from view1 to view2. I can't use `redirect` because the heavy processing of data of view 1 wouldn't be done (I guess).

Does someone know how can I transform my POST request into a GET and add a parameter ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you think the processing of data in `view1` wouldn't  be done on a redirect? A `HttpRedirectResponse` and its shortcut `redirect()` will simply give the user's browser a `302` HTTP response code, indicating that the browser should do a new request to the specified url and display that page instead of the current page.

It is actually good practice to *always*  do a redirect after a successful POST request. Otherwise, the data in the POST request would be sent and processed twice if the user refreshes the original page. Using a redirect will reset all POST data and prevent duplicate entries or error messages to the user after a successful request.

To pass a parameter, simply add it to the redirect url as you would with any GET parameter:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

parameters = QueryDict(foo='bar', myOtherVar='something_else')
url = '%s?%s' % (reverse('my_view_name'), parameters.urlencode())
return redirect(url)
```

Comment: That's what I did, I found ugly to hardcode the params in the url but the way you did it is nice !

Answer (score 3):

You can use this too:

```
def view(request):
   if request.method == "POST"
       #add the element
   #heavy processing for the context
```

here if the method is post, it will goto the post method if post is available and u can use the post perimeters in the processing u want

hope its useful, please vote up

or u can use:

```
from django.views.generic.base import View
class view(View):
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
      #heavy processing for the context

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      #add the element
```

when you'll call the above url with post method, it will goto post, and for other cases it will load get

Comment: I find it pretty elegant ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use request.REQUEST in that case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.REQUEST

But it seems bad idea, cause it will be deprecated in django 1.7. You shouldn't pass GET parameter to another view as POST, it would be better to use POST in booth views.